# How to demonstrate simple point-free style in JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, pointfree

The Point-Free style or the tacit programming is explained in wikipedia using Python.

```
def example(x):
  y = foo(x)
  z = bar(y)
  w = baz(z)
  return w
```

and..

```
def flow(fns):
    def reducer(v, fn):
        return fn(v)

    return functools.partial(functools.reduce, reducer, fns)

example = flow([baz, bar, foo])
```

How to demonstrate this effect using JS in the simplest understandable form of the concept?

Comment: Wouldn't chaining of array operations, or promises, or piping RxJS operators fit - kinda - the description? `someArray.filter(someFilter).map(someMapping).reduce(someReducer)`, `makeApiCall().then(doStuff).then(doOtherStuff).then(doMoreStuff)`, `makeApiCallButWithObservables().pipe(filter(someFn), map(someMap), switchMap(aDifferentKindOfMap))`?

Comment: @RobinZigmond My bad!. Corrected

Answer (score 2):

That can easily be turned into JS:

```
 function example(x) {
  const y = foo(x);
  const z = bar(y);
  const w = baz(z);
  return w;
}
```

...and

```
function flow(fns) {
  function reducer(v, fn) {
     return fn(v);
  }

  return fns.reduce.bind(fns, reducer);
}

const example = flow([baz, bar, foo]);
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `const = flow([foo, bar, buz])` ?

Comment: Sorry - I get it. It doesn't matter in function composition.

Answer (score 1):

This is function composition and the simplest solution is to just provide a composition combinator with the right arity for the given example:

```js
const foo = x => `foo(${x})`;
const bar = x => `bar(${x})`;
const baz = x => `baz(${x})`;

const comp3 = (f, g, h) => x => f(g(h(x)));

const fun = comp3(foo, bar, baz);

console.log(
  fun(123))
```

For this to work `comp3` is curried in its last argument and the function arguments are all unary functions.